# Most efficient way of passing callback function from any child frame to top window?

Tags: javascript, callback, frame

Below is the page with two iframes. This page has the javascript function called DoWork() which is called from any frame via window.top.DoWork.

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>TOP PARENT</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function DoWork(callback)
        {
            // do work here     

            callback();
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <iframe src="Frame1.htm"></iframe>        
    <iframe src="Frame2.htm"></iframe>        

</body>

</html>
```

The calling frame needs to pass a reference to its own function such that it can be called from the top most parent. For example

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Some frame</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function WorkIsDone()
        {
            alert('Work is done');
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Do Work" onclick="window.top.DoWork(WorkIsDone);" />    
</body>
</html>
```

**Question:** What is the most efficient way to globally reference function WorkIsDone() in the frame such that the top most frame can call it from function DoWork()?

Please note that I cannot hardcode the frame index in the call. Thanks!

**Update:** There can be nested frames within frames.

Comment: can't use use the child frame's .parent to get the frame with the function in it? no hardcoding, it's relative.

Comment: I could but only if there is one level of frames. If first frame has another frame in it, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question ... this is what I have came up with, however this is looping through all frames from top until current window is found. Perhaps there is a more efficient way of doing it

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Some frame</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function FindMe(source, me) {

            for (var i = 0; i < source.frames.length; i++) {

                if (source.frames[i] == me)
                    return source.frames[i];

                var r = FindMe(source.frames[i], me);

                if (r != null)
                    return r;
            }
        }

        function WorkIsDone()
        {
            alert('Work is done');
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Do Work" onclick="window.top.DoWork(FindMe(window.top, self).WorkIsDone);" />    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain this code? I'm newbie in JS but from my understanding `FindMe(window.top, self)` will always return `self`, no?